# Websphere -check the status of nodes from a browser for automation purpose | Python

Tags: python-3.x, websphere, monitor, email-notifications

I am writing a Python script to monitor the status of a certain websites and report if any error via email notification.

I am able to test the http status of the websites and websphere console urls.

Since the admin (console) is on DMGR , my code is able to check the status of only DMGR but not the nodes inside the DMGR ,whenever few env is down .. only node goes down. I need a way to monitor the node's status as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You application will be deployed to the JVMs on the nodes. 
Is your application configured to be accessible via the Node hostname [check virtualHost config]?
if yes - thats the url, you need to check.